# How do I stack 3 UI Elements with Auto layout

Tags: ios, swift

There is no stack at the bottom of the layout so how do I turn this into 1 stack view alternatively

Comment: Need a bit more information; what do you mean by "stack"? Don't know if it'll help, but you can select all three UI elements and then choose Editor -> Embed in -> View. Then you can apply constraints to that view.

Comment: Which xcode version you are using???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are using xcode 7 ,stack view is available from iOS9, if this thing holds good,select those UIelements (in your case buttons)which you want them to be in a stackView then go to 
Editor > EmbedIn > StackView, it will apply a Vertical stack view which can be changed in Attribute inspector or else you can drag and drop stack view from object library and add UI elements to it.